# A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter Xamarin.Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in a class called BaseViewModel in the following way ....

BASEVIEWMODEL.CS:

```
  public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            backingField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

With the aim that all my ViewModel inherit from the BaseViewModel and thus recycle code, but I have found the following problem when creating a property that depends on an attribute

[image: Screenshoot]

As you can see, my GymViewModel inherits from my BaseViewModel, how can I create a property that depends on an attribute? what am I doing wrong? any help for me?

Comment: Replace `gimnasio`'s  `{ get; set; }` with a semicolon. You meant it to be a backing *field* (not property), right?

Comment: Propose your answer to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler produces an error because you made `gimnasios` a property instead of a field:

```
private ObservableCollection<Gimnasio> gimnasios { get; set; }
```

As the compiler says, you're not allowed to pass a property as a `ref` parameter.

You probably intended `gimnasios` to be a backing *field* for the `Gimnasios` property, so replace `{ get; set; }` with a semicolon:

```
private ObservableCollection<Gimnasio> gimnasios;
```